# Drop down box selenium

Tags: java, junit, selenium

I have a drop down box with the id = PoolsSelect. I am trying to select the value within that drop down box but I'm getting an error, here is my code:

```
 RenderedWebElement element = (RenderedWebElement) driver.findElement(By.id("PoolsSelect"));
 RenderedWebElement target = (RenderedWebElement) driver.findElement(By.name("Austria"));

 element.dragAndDropOn(target);
```

and the error I get is

```
Error: Unable to find element by name using "PoolsSelect" (7)
```

I am using selenium 2.07a with JUnit 4.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

You say the **id** of the select is `PoolsSelect` but yet you're using a **By.name** selector.  Have you tried selecting by id?

Comment: yeah sorry i should of editted that i've used by.id and still having the same problem

Comment: This is the following code i've tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//PoolsSelect")).findElement(By.name("Austria")).click();